# Jquery context menu datas loaded from database

Tags: jquery, ajax, contextmenu

I'm using jquery context menu from  [this site](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/).

I would like to know if it is possible to load data into this context menu from a table of a database ?

I have tried everything and have been stuck on this problem for several weeks.

Comment: @ UweB, he can't he's tried *everything*.  SO's servers couldn't handle the entire codebase of the net!

Comment: What have you tried sofar? have a look at this, maybe this is the direction you want. http://jsfiddle.net/hlapidez/Md9QT/1/